# How can I stay on the same page, when I delete a record?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a comments system. Right now it is very simple. But I am a bit stuck.

I have a set off rooms that you can book. And for each of the rooms, you can submit comments to them.

When I click my to acess the comments of a room, I sent the room id with the URL, as you can see by the following code:

```
if (isset ( $_GET ['id'] )) {
    $room_id = $_GET ['id'];
}
$user_id = $_SESSION ['id'];

if ($_POST){
        extract($_POST);
        $register = $comment->createComment($room_id, $user_id, $comments);
}

?>
<div id="comments">
<?php  echo  $comment->getComments($room_id); ?>
</div>

<div id="comment-form">
  <h3>New Comment</h3>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="8"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

To get my comments I call my function `getComments($room_id)`

```
public function getComments($room_id) {

    $str = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE room_id = $room_id";
    $result = $this->db->mysqli->query ($str);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $string = "<table><thead><tr><th>#ID</th><th>Room id</th><th>user id</th><th>comments</th><th>Timestamp</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc () ) {
            $string .= "<tr><td>" . $row ['id'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row ['room_id'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row ['user_id'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row ['comments'] .
            "</td><td>" . $row ['timestamp'] .
            "</td><td>[<a href='deleteComment.php?id=" . $row ['id'] . "'>Delete</a>]</td> ";
        }
        $string .= "</tbody></table>";
        return $string;
    }
}
```

As you can see I create a link that goes to deleteComment.php and sent the link of the comment that I want to delete with it.

On that page I call a new function:

```
if ($comment->deleteComment($_GET['id']))
{
    echo "comment deleted"
}
else
{
    echo "Something went wrong.s";
}
```

And finally, my delete comment function:

```
public function deleteComment($id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = ?";
        if (!$result = $this->db->mysqli->prepare($sql))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$result->bind_param('i', $id))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return $result->execute();
    }
```

All of this is working. But **my question is:** How can I delete the comments and still stay on the original page that displays the comments, and not go to the deleteComments.php page? I'm not looking for an AJAX solution. It would be nice if I could just stick to PHP.

Comment: Use header() to redirect again after delete or use AJAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rakesh suggested, you can use the header() function in your deleteComment function or you can just link to the same page but with comment id to be deleted

instead of:

```
href='deleteComment.php?id=" . $row ['id'] . "'>
```

do:

```
href='?id=" . $row ['delete_comment_id'] . "'>
```

and delete the comment before creating the list of comments

Answer (score 0):

Just link the delete "button" to the normal comments page with a seperate delete GET or POST value (instead of id), then at the beginning of your comments page if it is set.

Eg: yourpage.com/comments.php?delete=14

```
if (isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    $comment->deleteComment($_GET['delete']);
}
```

BUT(!) really be aware, the way you are doing it, allows for any user to delete any comment by entering its id, this is not safe!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The comments can only be deleted by a logged in admin. :-)